# Not able to refresh the page from the controller action (ASP.NET MVC Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can successfully compile the SCSS file in the Change method but client side wwwroot directory is not updated until I press the browser refresh button.

Is there any way to trigger the refresh event in this Change action method?

I have tried all redirection method but it is not working. Any help will be helpful. Please help me to overcome this.

`View (index.cshtml)

```
<button onclick="clickHandler">Change Theme</button>
```

Script (site.js)

```
function clickHandler() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/Change",
        data: { jsonData: JSON.stringify("") },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("saved successfully");
        }
    })
}
```

Controller Action (HomeController.cs)

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Change()
        {
            string basePath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string importFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "import.scss");
            string inputFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "custom.scss");
            string importContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(importFilePath);
            string inputContent = "$accent: #08f410;\n$accent-font: #e3165b;" + importContent;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(inputFilePath, inputContent);
            string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "custom.css");

            CompilationOptions options = new CompilationOptions
            {
                IncludePaths = new[] { "node_modules/@{third-party-package}/" }
            };
            CompilationResult result = SassCompiler.CompileFile(inputFilePath, outputFilePath, null, options);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, result.CompiledContent);
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Layout

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - DynamicTheme</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/custom.css" />
```

Comment: Any update? Does my reply has helped you?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging data with a web server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.

That means, if you don't set any reload logic in the ajax success method, it will not refresh the whole page(no matter what you have done in the MVC controller).

It will send the request to the MVC action without refreshing the whole page and get the view html result as the response.

If you want to refresh the page after the ajax has successfully executed, I suggest you could try to call `location.reload(true);`method in the ajax success method.

More details, you could refer to this site.js codes:

```
function clickHandler() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/Change",
        data: { jsonData: JSON.stringify("") },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("saved successfully");
            location.reload(true);
        }
    })
}
```